# Optimizing redraws of multiple View objects

Tags: android, performance

I am creating an android app that is essentially a dashboard with many gauges and indicators on it. I have a Main View which is added in the  Main Activity's onCreate() method. Each gauge is a custom View object which is added and initialized in the Main View and drawn in the Main View's  onDraw() method. The gauge values are constantly updated by individual threads that are launched in the Main Activity's onCreate() method. When a thread detects the need to change a gauge value, it does so, and then sends a message to the Main View (via a message handler) telling it that the particular gauge needs to be updated (redrawn).   I am using invalidate() in the Main View's message handler to refresh the screen. The app runs well, but I am wondering if I am handling the display updates as efficiently as I can. My question is:

When I call invalidate() in the Main View, I assume it is redrawing all the gauge Views, even the ones that have not changed. If so, would it be more efficient to just redraw the View of the gauge that has changed? What is the best way to do that? I have tried calling the individual View's invalidate() and postInvalidate() methods but neither works.

As requested, here is the current state of the onDraw method in the Main View. Eventually there will be a lot more gauges added. The Bezels are static and only change if the device switches configuration (landscape/portrait). The various gauges are instantiated from a Gauge class which extends View:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    speedoBezel.draw(canvas);
    tachBezel.draw(canvas);
    oilPressBezel.draw(canvas);
    oilTempBezel.draw(canvas);

    speedoGauge.draw(canvas);
    tachGauge.draw(canvas);
    oilPressGauge.draw(canvas);
    oilTempGauge.draw(canvas);

}
```

---

Ok, I have read so many ways to animate in Android I started to mix them up. I would like to rephrase the question:

If I am developing an app with many different objects in the main view that changed  frequently but at different intervals, is it better performance wise to:

1. Add the objects to the main view and use the invalidate(rect) in the main view to update them individually as needed, or
2. Add each object to a Layout and use invalidate on each view when they require updating.

Important to note that none of the objects overlap

Comment: I have tried the invalidate(Rect dirty) method but in some of my simulations, there is a little bit of aliasing on the edges of the Rect where it overlaps another gauge. I have not tried it in real time, so it might work fine, but again, I was wondering what the most efficient way to do this is.

Comment: show us some of the important parts of your code, like the onDraw method of the MainView , i may help

Comment: Why don't you use a layout in which you put all your custom views , and invalidate each one of them separately ? 
Your MainView should extend a layout (Linear or relative layout ).
In your code here your custom views are not really children of the MainView, all they do is modifying the canvas, ie there is only one big view which is the MainView

Comment: doing it the way you did, your views do not even need to extend the View class, all you need in them is a draw method, this is all you're using here

Comment: Thanks. See my rephrased question above.